# JS Modules Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: getActualGrid is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1"

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-modules

I'm trying to make a 2D Array for Conway's Game of Life, but when I try to use the functions in the console for testing I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getActualGrid is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I don't understand where is it coming from. The functions are in global scope, yet it's like they weren't. When I use my code to run them it works fine (I add the commands that I want to use in the console at the end of the file), but I'm not being able to use them in my web browser. I assume It's because of modules usage...

Is there any way to solve this??

My HTML and JS code:

```js
let rows = 9;
let columns = 9;
const width = 20;

export const generateGrid = () => {
  let grid = "<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class='grid__container'>";
  for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    grid += "<tr>";
    for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
      grid += `<td id="cell-${x + "-" + y}">`;
      grid += "</td>";
    }
    grid += "</tr>";
  }
  grid += "</table>";
  let table = document.querySelector("#grid");
  table.innerHTML = grid;

  let gridContainer = document.querySelector(".grid__container");
  gridContainer.style.height = width * rows + "px";
  gridContainer.style.width = width * columns + "px";

  let cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
  cells.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
      let cell = event.target;
      changeStatus(cell);
    });
  });
};

export const changeStatus = (cell) => {
  if (cell.style.background != "gray") {
    cell.style.background = "gray";
  } else {
    cell.style.background = "";
  }
};

let actualGrid = [];
export const getActualGrid = () => {
  actualGrid = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    actualGrid.push([]);
    for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
      let cell = document.querySelector(`#cell-${x + "-" + y}`);
      actualGrid[y][x] = cell.style.background == "gray";
    }
  }
};

generateGrid();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./src/assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/css/table.css">
  <title>The Game of Life</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grid" class="grid"></div>
  <script type="module" src="./src/js/index.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything work fine when I run it, I mean I got the

Comment: You never use this function in the code you included

Comment: I'm trying to use it in console since it saves the "actualGrid" after you clicked on different boxes, and I want to make sure they save as they should

Comment: It's not in global scope, you would have to add it to `window` like `window.getActualGrid = getActualGrid`

Comment: It actually worked... can you explain me why?? How is it not declared globally?? Been looking for documentation that explains this but couldn't find any

Comment: That's because of `type="module"` [Module-defined variables are scoped to the module unless explicitly attached to the global object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts)

Comment: I hadn't come across that page on mdn before.
Thanks!!